# NSURLConnection with large Base64 JSON body

Tags: objective-c, json, web-services, post, nsurlconnection

I'm having a strange and annoying problem with my requests to our webservice.
I'm attempting to send base64 encoded strings via JSON (along with some other content) via the NSURLRequest and NSURLConnection methods.

The code below works for small base64 encoded images, such as 64x64 pixel avatars, but its not working for larger b64 strings for some strange reason it returns an "Bad Request , 400" error.
I'm using the POST method and the string length is around 10,000 characters long.
The webservice works for everything except for these large strings, I have tried 3 different b64 parsing solutions with none of them working.
Unfortuantly i'm the front end coder and have little webservice experience so any assistance is appreciated.

```
    NSData *postData = [JSONRequest dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URLRequest]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];
    [request setTimeoutInterval:9999.0f];
    [request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData];
    [request setHTTPShouldUsePipelining:NO];



    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:delegateData];

    [connection start];
    [connection release];
    [request release];
    NSLog(@"Connection to %@!",URLRequest);
```

And the response is caught here:

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{

     NSLog(@"didRecieveResponse");

     // cast the response to NSHTTPURLResponse so we can look for 404 etc
     NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
     NSLog(@"Response:%@ StatusCode: %i",[NSHTTPURLResponse localizedStringForStatusCode:[httpResponse statusCode]],[httpResponse statusCode]);
     if ([httpResponse statusCode] >= 400)
         // do error handling here
}
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Hi Oliver! I'm having a similar problem as you can see in that question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14910142/uploading-large-images-using-base64-and-json-ios Do you know how to solve it? In that case, I'd be grateful if you could give me some advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seemed that the server response was due to the Webservice configuration in dealing with large requests.
Although I wasn't directly involved in the server-side aspect of the project, it was discussed that it was a combination of:
Server Caching
Connecting timeout intervals
Connectivity packet loss / quality of service issues.

AKA, It was a server-side issue and not a iOS specific client issue.

Comment: Thanks Oliver! I'll comment that to the server-side programmer.